# jQuery Ajax PHP JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hi I'm just after some advice/input.

I'm developing an application that has a MySQL backend, it has HTML pages that use jQuery to access PHP pages returning the data from MySQL in JSON.

Now, what I need to know is there a disadvantage to working like this.

The main advantage I can see that I can seperate the presentation layer and data access layer. Therefore it speeds up development once I have setup the objects in PHP.

One of the main disadvantages I can see (or I think I can see) is that Google won't be able to see the results inserted by jQuery Ajax/JSON.

Open to any advice, thanks in advance.

Regards, Andy

Comment: Probably of interest: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you enable your application to work for users without JavaScript support as well. If you do that you'll have a quick application for your visitors with JavaScript, you'll have a working application for visitors without and Google won't have any problems indexing it.

Comment: So are you saying do 2 versions?

If it's an issue I'll just do it in php, another advantage would be that people wouldn't be able to call my PHP pages and see my JSON.

Comment: You need to check for the request type to decide whether to output json or html. If using through Ajax request return json content or return html content. check 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' header